# NSPageController not allowed, but settings are set to OS X 10.8

Tags: objective-c, xcode, compiler-construction

I am using an NSPageController in my app, in Targets -> Summary, Deployment Target is set to 10.8.

In Targets -> Info, Minimum system version is `${MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET}`

In Targets -> Build Settings, OS X Deployment Target is set to `OS X 10.8`.

In Projects -> Info, OS X Deployment Target is set to `10.8`.

In Projects -> Build Settings, Base SDK is set to `"Latest OS X (OS X 10.8)"`. Compiller is `Apple LLVM compiler 4.2`. And OS X Deployment Target says `OS X 10.8`.

However, after doing all of this, when I try to build I get `"Class Unavailable: NSPageController on OS X versions prior to 10.8"`

Any ideas. I tried cleaning. I am on OS X 10.8.2, with the latest stable version of Xcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One more place to check is the deployment version of the nib file.
This has tripped me up a few times.